# Caching links for multiple paths

Tags: c, dijkstra

I'm writing the code for an algorithm that finds multiple paths between a source and a destination. Which would be the best way to store the paths I get from modified Dijkstra in every iteration in order to delete interlacing ones later on? i get the path from a vector named previous starting from the destination until i reach the source. A matrix doesnt seem to work for every path.

```
int l[SDIM][SDIM];
int d[SDIM], s[SDIM], p[SDIM];
int i,j,a,z,prev,minD,minJ,count;
for (i=0;i<SDIM;i++)
{
    d[i]=l[a][i];
    s[i]=1;
    p[i]=a;
}
s[a] = 0;
prev=a;
do
{
    minD=MAX;
    for (j=0;j<SDIM;j++)
    {
        if ((s[j]==1) && (d[j]<minD))
        {
            minD=d[j];
            minJ=j;
        }
    }
    s[minJ] = 0;
    prev=minJ;
    if (prev==z) break;
    for (i=0;i<SDIM;i++)
    {
        if ((l[prev][i]!=MAX) && (d[i]>(d[prev]+l[prev][i])))
        {
            d[i]=d[prev]+l[prev][i];
            p[i]=prev;
            s[i]=1;
        }
    }
}while(1);
```

Comment: You are not telling anything about how you are structuring your data.

Comment: i'm working with vectors and a weigh-link matrix.

Comment: Im posting the implementation of Dijkstra

Comment: Why don't you indent your code?

Comment: @RafałRawicki, i made the four space formatting.